# Mysql - "With recursive" not working with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy, recursive-cte

I'm trying to print from a db the categories in a hierarchy order. I have developed a mysql code that sort of works in dbfiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/_oUW-eW_), but I am not able to make it run in PHP.

The mysql code is the following:

```
with recursive cteBottomToTop
    AS (select id, name, title, parentid
        from $treedb
        where id = $start  
      union all
    select c.id, c.name, c.title, c.parentid
        from $treedb c
        inner join cteBottomToTop cte
          on c.id = cte.parentid)
    select *
    from cteBottomToTop
```

The PHP code used is the following:

```
    $sqltree = ("with recursive cteBottomToTop
    AS (select id, name, title, parentid
        from $treedb
        where id = $start  
      union all
    select c.id, c.name, c.title, c.parentid
        from $treedb c
        inner join cteBottomToTop cte
          on c.id = cte.parentid)
    select *
    from cteBottomToTop");
    $result = mysql_query($sqltree);
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "n";
        $error = $error.$message;
    }else{
    $number = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if ($number < 1) {
           $error = $error."<p>Problemi nel caricare dal DB_tree</p>";
           }else{
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               $name_print[] = $row["name"];
               $title_print[] = $row["title"];
               $parentid_print[] = $row["parentid"];
           }
       }
    }
```

The code returns the following error:
`Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive cteBottomToTop AS (select id, name, title, parentid from ' at line 1n`

Please note that the version of my MySql server is 5.7.30

Any help?

Comment: Any particular reason for not sharing the exact error message with us?

Comment: @Shadow thanks for flagging; I updated the text. Best

Comment: Please print out the error you get in "if (!$result) {". Apparently, the query failed (so $result is false, but you just continue to the next part ($number = mysqli_num_rows($result);) which assumes $result is NOT "false" (e.g. that the query worked, but it didnt).

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Version of the server is 5.7.30; I'm also using PhpMYAdmin v. 5.2.0

Comment: CTEs are not supported by MySql versions prior to 8.0